# UIActionSheet dismissed with outside tap hangs interface on iPad

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiactionsheet

I'm pretty sure this is an Xcode bug, but wanted to bounce it off the brain trust here to make sure I'm not missing anything obvious.

Build a standard Master-Detail Swift app in the latest Xcode.  Add the action sheet lines (see code below) to didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  App works fine for iPhone simulator, but for iPad, if you tap off of the ActionSheet to dismiss it, the interface hangs.  No crash, but I do see this when the action sheet is shown for the iPad simulator and not the iPhone sim:

```
2014-07-10 22:24:26.661 totMasterDetail[33543:1903550] 
Assuming sourceView is not nil
2014-07-10 22:24:26.670 totMasterDetail[33543:1903550] 
Assuming sourceView is not nil
```

Not seeing anything in the docs or the release notes: bug, or am I missing something obvious?

(I'll file bug with Apple if it's not me)

as always, many thanks!

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad {
        let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate
        self.detailViewController!.detailItem = object
    }
    let actionSheet = UIActionSheet()
    actionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("title")
    actionSheet.showInView(self.tableView)

}
```

Comment: fyi: Reported it to Apple

Answer (score 0):

Fixed for me in Xcode 6 beta 4